Why can't root bypass permissions in an ID-mapped mount?
Why does global root (root in the initial user namespace) not have the ability to read all files regardless of permission when ID-mapped mounts (see "ID-mapped mounts" under man 2 mount_setattr and "X-mount.idmap" under man 8 mount) are in use? Minimal test case:
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/idmaptest bs=1M count=10
mkfs.ext4 /tmp/idmaptest
mount /tmp/idmaptest /mnt -o X-mount.idmap=1000:0:1
ls -l /mnt/lost+found

After doing all of the above as root, the final command will fail with a permission denied error. (By the way, this isn't specific to lost+found. Any other directory that's not world-readable will exhibit the same behavior.) This surprises me, because I definitely have CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH and CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE in the initial user namespace, and man 7 user_namespaces says "If a process has a capability in a user namespace, then it has that capability in all child (and further removed descendant) namespaces as well.", so I expect to have them everywhere. Even weirder, if I try to do chmod 755 /mnt/lost+found, it fails with EOVERFLOW (Value too large for defined data type), which man 2 chmod doesn't even mention as a possible error from that syscall. Is what I'm seeing intentional behavior, or a bug? If it's intentional, why? And either way, is there any workaround other than unmounting and remounting it without ID mapping enabled?

Maybe: Biederman: "When you are doing anything non-trivial you need to be performing it in a process that has it's uids and gids mapped." (https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=183461) man 8 mount: "If any user IDs or group IDs are not mapped, all
files owned by that unmapped user or group ID will appear as
being owned by the overflow user ID or overflow group ID
respectively."  You have not mapped UID 0 to a UID on the mounted FS (although you have the other way around).  Not sure why CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH wouldn't work though.

No data scientist worth their salt in data security would ever map  localUID 0 to anything non-zero on a remote mount filesystem.

@JohnGreene What's "remote" about anything in my question?

sorry.  data abstraction being misstated as remote also refers to data hiding principle.

@JohnGreene I still don't understand what that has to do with what I asked.
